# Tool to get all the Google page ranks of a website

Tags: pagerank, ranking

I have a website, I was searching for a tool get the google page ranks of my website But I didn't get the appropriate one. Can anyone suggest tool to do this. (data export options to csv/excel will be appreciated).

Comment: If you're looking for recommendations or suggestions you should ask in [chat]

Answer (score 1):

I use a tool called SEO for Chrome.

It shows PageRank, internal links, Alexa rank, SEM rush value, no-follow links and loads more

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/seo-for-chrome/oangcciaeihlfmhppegpdceadpfaoclj

Answer (score 0):

Few time ago, I used a good plugin for Firefox to get Pagerank and seo data from a website. This plugin is now available for many web browser like Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera... and it works well.

This was my favourite because you can get many data like Pagerank, links to the site, Alexa rank... Data are displayed on demand for a website but also on Google search results (very useful to analyze competition).

You can check it: http://www.seoquake.com.